# The no. of positive integral solutions of the eqn. a×b×c×d×e=1050

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, multinomial-coefficients, multinomial-theorem

Find the total no. of positive integral solutions to the equation

a×b×c×d×e=1050

I came across this problem while practicing problems in multinomial theorem.....but I have no idea how we can apply it here....also tried out a few other logics but none of them seems to work.....can anyone help me out?

Comment: Hint: [Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $1050 = 2^1 \cdot 3^1 \cdot 5^2 \cdot 7^1$, each factor will be of the form $2^{a_k}3^{b_k}5^{c_k}7^{d_k}$, $k = 1,\ldots, 5$ and 
\begin{align*}
\sum a_k = 1, \quad \sum b_k = 1, \quad \sum c_k = 2, \quad \sum d_k = 1
\end{align*}
The number of solutions of the above are $5, 5, 15, 5$ and hence the number of solutions is $5\cdot 5 \cdot 15 \cdot 5 = 1875$

Comment: Thanks guys!! I missed out on some basics on this question.....hahaha....Thanks again!!

Comment: @Muralidharan: This count 1875 looks huge. Perhaps you are counting ordered tuples $(a,b,c,d,e)$ such that their product is 1050.

Comment: Yes, they are ordered tuples (since we have distinct variables $a,b,c,d,e$) If we disregard the order, we must ask the question as "how many ways can we write 1050 as product of five integers?"

Comment: @Muralidharan Your solution is correct according to my answer key...which mentions the same no.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the tag combination attached your question I interpret your question as counting the number of  integer sequences $a\ge b\ge c\ge d\ge e\ge1$ such  that $abcde=1050$.

One can split this into  various cases according as how many of these 5 factors are 1.  This leads to far fewer count. Take the prime factorization that yields 5 prime factors (not distinct).
$$1050= 5\times5 \times 7\times3\times 2=abcde$$

Case I. $e=1$, $a,b,c,d>1$: By unique factorization, we have to club two of the 5 primes into a single factor.  There are 7 ways of achieving this.

Case II. $d=e=1; a,b,c> 1$. Either we can club 3 primes, calling it $a$ and  retaining the other two as $b$ and $c$; or club two primes in pairs and call them  and retain the other. This also leads to 13 more possibilities

Case III & IV $a>1,c,d,e=1, b=1,b\ne1$. This is number of ways of factoring $1050$ into two factors, which is same as $d(n)$,number of divisors of $1050$, This is 24.

And one more case all the five factors > 1 which has just one possibility.
So the answer is $24+7+13+1=45$
I hope I haven't missed anything.